# ¿Por que ReCapcha no implementa el data-size normal o compact con el evento resize js?

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente chapcha:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxx" data-size="normal"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y el siguiente evento que me captura el ancho de la pantalla:

```
//Evento para capturar el ancho de la paguina y compactar el rechapcha
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 540) {
    document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha').setAttribute('data-size','compact');
  }else{
    document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha').setAttribute('data-size','normal');
  };
});
```

Esos atributos se implementan  correctamente pero el chapcha sigue con el mismo tamaño ('normal').

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que reCaptcha usa los atributos de datos solo para generar el elemento, es decir, al cargar la página, ignorando los cambios que hagas posteriormente.

Lo que puedes hacer es dejar siempre `data-size="normal"` y crear reglas en css de acuerdo al tamaño de pantalla, por ejemplo, si el ancho de pantalla es menor de 540 pixeles, reducir reCaptcha al 80%:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 539px){
    .g-recaptcha {
        transform:scale(0.80);
    }
}
```

Tal vez tengas que revisar otras resoluciones y modificar el porcentaje para que se vea correcto.